# Groovy Regular Expression Include Lines Around

Tags: regex, groovy

How can I use regular expressions to match a pattern and return the lines around it in Groovy?

For example, if I have the following text:

```
    Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1              4185956   1206996   2762888  31% /
    /dev/sda11            30679784  28324040    772140  98% /extra
    <..lines omitted..>
    fas3050c-1-2.b:/vol/canis
                          10485760   6599936   3885824  63% /nfs/data_d2/dog_data
    fas6070-1-1.b:/vol/felis
                         314572800  54889600 259683200  18% /nfs/DATA-1/cat_data

We want the available disk space in KB, for /nfs/data remote
disk partitions, which is "3885824" and "259683200" in the sample
above. Note that partitions that start out with "/nfs/data" may be
either upper or lower case. Capture the partition name for debugging.

Capture the space available in KB as the number before the
percentage number (digits followed by '%'). The pattern match
is relying on there being just one instance of a numeric
percentage (\d+%) occurring in the each usable output line.
```

I want is to match the pattern `We want the available` as well as the 5 lines above and below it, to give the following output:

```
fas3050c-1-2.b:/vol/canis
                      10485760   6599936   3885824  63% /nfs/data_d2/dog_data
fas6070-1-1.b:/vol/felis
                     314572800  54889600 259683200  18% /nfs/DATA-1/cat_data

We want the available disk space in KB, for /nfs/data remote
disk partitions, which is "3885824" and "259683200" in the sample
above. Note that partitions that start out with "/nfs/data" may be
either upper or lower case. Capture the partition name for debugging.

Capture the space available in KB as the number before the
```

Comment: Is this basically a college assignment? Or a question for an interview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```regex
(.*\n){0,5}We want the available.*(\n.*){0,5}
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/4BtEAX/3) (with capture groups, so it looks nice)

It works by finding:

- `(.*\n){0,5}` - Up to 5 sets of "any amount of characters follow by a newline"
- `We want the available` Your text
- `.*` - The rest of that line
- `(\n.*){0,5}` Up to 5 sets of "a newline followed by any amount of characters"

This regex will capture **as many** lines as possible above and below (up to 5), so doesn't break if there are less (or none).

You can use this in Groovy to find the first match by calling:

```groovy
def snippet = yourString.find(/(.*\n){0,5}We want the available.*(\n.*){0,5}/)
```

Or call it with `findAll()` to get every match.